# "delete" button in the user profile

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Why the "delete" button present on some sites (on the profile page) of SE network, but not on the other?

For example, I have "delete" on [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), [Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). But not on other.

Comment: You can delete your account yourself where you have no actitvities so far.

Comment: You don't *have* an account on Pro Webmasters (anymore?).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, just was too curious about this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any account that has not yet seen any activity that could earn you or others reputation, or where you interacted with the site beyond getting your association bonus and browsing, can be deleted.

This lets you clean up your account list a little, if you signed up for a few sites you didn't actually use in the end.

Once you've posted questions or answers, or suggested edits to posts, or commented on posts, or voted, or flagged a post or comment (beyond spam and offensive flags), your account can no longer be deleted directly by you. Note that participation in the site's *Meta* also counts (outside of Stack Overflow / Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Anyway, looks strange, I haven't done almost anything on [Drupal.SE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13041/m0nhawk?tab=activity), but don't have button...

Comment: @m0nhawk: You have the Citizen Patrol badge, for flagging a post. Check your flag count. :-)